# Any ideas how to remove a background color of a button?

Tags: ios, background

I am trying to remove the pink color of this button, but it seems that I can't. I have looked inside my code and I couldn't find a line where I set it to be pink. Any ideas how to remove it, it should be transparent.

[image]

Comment: check button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Comment: yourbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the background color to clear will make the button transparent.

```
btSeeWhatsThere.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear()
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this

check `button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

You can also check this in the interface builder

[image]

I hope this helps you